# Python, Loops, Multiples

Tags: python, loops

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong; I keep getting a traceback error.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or point me in the right direction, please?

```
Multiples = str(input('Multiples of 13 from 200 to 100'))
for counter in range(max):
    for i in reversed(list(range(100,201))):
        if i%13==0:
            print(i,'total','*= 13')
            list1 = {}
            for j in list(range(2,i+1)):
                if i%j == 00:
                list1 = []
                print(list1)
```

I am trying to get the output to look like the following:

```
Multiples of 13 from 200 to 100
195 = 13 times 15
182 = 13 times 14
169 = 13 times 13
156 = 13 times 12
143 = 13 times 11
130 = 13 times 10
117 = 13 times 9
104 = 13 times 8
```

Also, could someone tell me how to enter code in this block, because each time I click on the code or <kbd>CTRL-K</kbd> my format is off?

Comment: What is the traceback?

Comment: Please make sure you also provide us the specific values of the variables you've declared here. For example, what is `max`? Where does it come from?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan `max` is a builtin

Comment: @SMSvonderTann It's a built-in _function_, not an integer that can be fed into range like OP is doing here. :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're overcomplicating things..

```
output = []
x = 0
while True: 
    if 13 * x > 200:
        break
    output.append('{0} = 13 times {1}'.format(13*x, x))
    x += 1

for x in reversed(output):
    print(x)
```

**Output**

```
195 = 13 times 15
182 = 13 times 14
169 = 13 times 13
156 = 13 times 12
143 = 13 times 11
130 = 13 times 10
117 = 13 times 9
104 = 13 times 8
91 = 13 times 7
78 = 13 times 6
65 = 13 times 5
52 = 13 times 4
39 = 13 times 3
26 = 13 times 2
13 = 13 times 1
0 = 13 times 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually quite a few things that are preventing the output from looking like you want it to:

1. In `Multiples = str(input('Multiples of 13 from 200 to 100'))`, asking for `input` prompts the *user* to input a number, and will then assign *that* input to `Multiples`.
2. You're not actually printing `Multiples of 13 from 200 to 100`.
3. `max` is not a number, so you can't call `range` on it. I've assumed you haven't defined `max` elsewhere, of course, so if you have, kindly update your code to include it.
4. `print(i,'total','*= 13')` will print `<number> total *=13`. This does not remotely resemble the output you want.
5. You never actually *insert* anything into `list1` before printing it. Even if you did, it would appear inside a list so it would look like `[<element>]`.

Since the code as provided is not a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that would let us pinpoint your exact error, I suspect you will need to rewrite your code from scratch - as written, none of it conforms to the output you want to get. This is far more complicated than it has to be in any case.

All you have to do is

- Go through the numbers 201, 200, ... 100
- Check if each number is divisible by 13
- Use the handy division operator `/` to get the value of the number divided by 13 as a float (a decimal number) and convert it to integer by using `int()`.

Here's a minimal example of the right way to do this:

```
print('Multiples of 13 from 200 to 100') # prints this string
for i in range(201,100,-1): # iterate through 201, 200, 199 ... 100
    if i % 13 == 0: # checks if number is divisible by 13 ...
        # prints out the result of number divided by 13 in the format you want
        print(i, '= 13 times', int(i/13))
```

Comment: I recommend using `'{0} = 13 times {1}'.format(i, int(i/13))` imo It's much cleaner.

Comment: @Signal: Perhaps, but I'd rather not beat OP's head with `format` if they're having trouble with loops :)

Comment: Fair, but at least remove the space at the end of 'times' so you have a single space rather than two :)

Comment: @Signal Done as requested.